# Android ActionBarSherlock SearchView change icon

Tags: android, search, icons, actionbarsherlock, searchview

I am looking for a way to change default searchView icon, if possible without Java code.
This code doesn't work because it can be used in API 21 :

```
"android:searchViewStyle"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your parent theme in style.xml

```
<item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/ic_action_search</item>
```

Comment: FYI: if you are building your app now try to avoid ABS as it is no more supported, have a look at appcompat library from google